# Why does IntPtr not implement IEquatable<IntPtr>?

Tags: c#, boxing, intptr, iequatable

I was seeing a rather large amount of garbage collector stalls in my application, so I profiled it, and saw that a lot of garbage was being generated by a method of mine that did nothing more than this:

`return Address.Equals(other.Address)`

Where `Address` is an `IntPtr`.

Turns out that `IntPtr` does not implement `IEquatable<T>` like most value types, and therefore I was boxing `other.Address` each time.

Is there any good reason for `IntPtr` not implementing that interface, or is this an oversight?

Comment: I had a look in the [reference source for IntPtr](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,d99bf6ad49979009) and couldn't see any signs for why it doesn't. Perhaps it is an oversight - if they implement Equals, why not IEquatable?

Comment: Well I'm asking this question because I wondered if it might have something to do with the fact that IntPtr changes size according to the target arch. But if there is no good reason, I will raise a bug somewhere (not sure where I should yet, though, haha). Also I was a little frustrated ;)

Comment: To turn it around on you, is there a good reason you don't just have `Address == other.Address`?

Comment: Only that the line I wrote was inside my own `Equals()` method, so I was 'following suit', if you get what I mean. Having said that, now that I've found the problem, I've changed the line to `Address == other.Address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an oversight. `IEquatable<T>` was added in .NET 2.0 after `IntPtr` existed. There are a few places in the BCL that were not upgraded properly and nobody seems interested in fixing them.

Just use `==`. It is better style anyway because it clearly shows your intent.